# Using JWT and x509 in Spring

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, x509certificate, x509

I have to implement both JWT and x509 in Spring. Basically scenario would be:

- user tries to enter an endpoint, let's say `/info` To do this he should provide JWT and if he doesn't have any (or it's invalid) a x509 certificate would have to be presented to identify himself
- after making sure such user actually exists new JWT would be generated and passed to the user, so he can then present himself with it when requesting mentioned `/info` endpoint

I don't want to ask for x509 cert in each request - just after JWT expiration or in case of lack of such

Now, I have implemented getting JWT (working fine) and authenticating users with x509 (working fine) separately but Im having troubles connecting those two things to work together as intented.

JWT part:

```
http
   .cors()
   .and().csrf().disable()
   .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPointJwt).and()
   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
   .and()
   .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
   .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userService))
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
   .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
```

x509 part:

```
http
   .authorizeRequest()
   .anyRequest()
   .authenticated()
   .and()
   .x509()
   .subjectPrincipalRegex("XX=(.*?)")
   .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this working?